# SQL Missing Secondary FileGroup

Tags: sql-server

Recently I added a secondary file group to my database. As of last night that second.ndf file was removed and is no where to be seen "not recoverable". The second.ndf does not have any files on it which I need. Now that it is gone the database will not start or recover as it keeps complaining about the missing second.ndf. How can I recover this database and have it ignore the second file group? The database is set to simple as the data is not important so I do not have a backup to restore from but the structure of the database is important. Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Backups are useful for both structure *and* data. Source control is useful for structure, if structure was important, why is it not in source control?

Comment: I do have a backup from 2 months ago which I could restore but I would rather restore what I have. The primary mdf and ldf are fine I just can't get the database to start due to the missing ndf.

Comment: I am a little concerned that you were able to delete a database file from an attached database.  How was that done?

Comment: I did not delete the file I was doing some testing on a faster drive that is used for temp storage which periodically is cleaned up. I did not even think twice that if the secondary filegroup was deleted it would just take down the whole db. I am pretty new to this and had no idea it could not just tell you it could not find that file and still start.

Comment: The more I look into it the more I feel like I am just going to have to go back to my old backup. Seems pretty crazy that the database can't start even though everything it needs is still there except for a secondary file group.